# Allow unique values twice in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, office-365, office-365-developer

Example :
I am having Employee related list named as "ABC".
This ABC list has field name as "Assigned To" which is person field.
now i want to add records for single person only , which will allow me to save only 2 records.

example -

Assigned to  |    Status 
Person1      |  OK 
Person1      |  OK 
Person1      | should not allow

---

I know, we can do it by javascript+rest api or using other codes.

Still want to know if this possible with minimal efforts like using **Calculated Column** or any other method.

Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using InfoPath. InfoPath is the best and minimal way to do simple things like this.

Comment: i think infopath is not supported in SharePoint Online

Answer (score -2):

You can just do it by javascript+rest api or using other codes.

There is no minimal efforts like using Calculated Column or any other method.

Comment: yeah, i have done it using JS REST.. but wanted to check if any simple approach for the same. Thank you.